# Make a table in javsascript with different secondary column each time?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript so this code probably has a lot of mistakes.
But what I am creating is a dog meal calculator, it prints out a table of calculations but I can't seem to join the answers together in the second column. two, three, four, etc are variables for the month calculations what I want printed out on the second column, is there a way to make a loop or something?
Thanks in advance.
This is the code:

```
            function mainPup() {
            var link = "<a href='file:///D:/Desktop/calc/index.html'>Enter another weight</a>"
            var kilos = document.getElementById('input1').value
            var two = kilos * 80
            var three = kilos * 70
            var four = kilos * 60
            var five = kilos * 50
            var six = kilos * 45
            var seven = kilos * 40
            var eight = kilos * 35
            var nine = kilos * 35
            var ten = kilos * 30
            var eleven = kilos * 30
            var twelve = kilos * 12
            var all = two + "<br>" + three + "<br>" + four + "<br>" + five + "<br>" + six + "<br>" + seven + "<br>" + eight + "<br>" + nine + "<br>" + ten + "<br>" + eleven + "<br>" + twelve
            var months = "Months"
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = kilos + "kg Puppy needs daily:";
            document.getElementById("months").innerHTML = months;
            document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = all;
            document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = link;
            var kilos = document.getElementById('input1').value
            try {
                var table = Number(kilos);
                if (kilos == 0) {
                    alert("Please Enter Value");
                } else {

                    var output = "<table border='2'><thead><th>Month</th><th>Mince</th>></thead><tbody>";
                    for (var num = 1; num <= 12; num++) {
                        output += "</td><td>" + num + "</td><td>" + all + "</td></tr>";
                    }
                    output += "</tbody></table>";
                    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = output;
                }
            } catch (err) {}
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, given your requirements, based on the image you attached, I think you need:

```js
    function mainPup() {
      // REMOVED for testing only
      //var link = "<a href='file:///D:/Desktop/calc/index.html'>Enter another weight</a>"
      //var kilos = document.getElementById('input1').value
      // ADDED for testing only
      var kilos = 2;
      // Multipliers for each month - note that this is zero-based, so 0 and 1 are not required
      // the first value in the output will be month=2, so that is the third item in this list
      var monthly = [0, 0, 80, 70, 60, 50, 45, 40, 35, 35, 30, 30, 12];
      // var all = two + "<br>" + three + "<br>" + four + "<br>" + five + "<br>" + six + "<br>" + seven + "<br>" + eight + "<br>" + nine + "<br>" + ten + "<br>" + eleven + "<br>" + twelve
      var months = "Months"
      // REMOVED for testing purposes only
      // document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = kilos + "kg Puppy needs daily:";
      // document.getElementById("months").innerHTML = months;
      // document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = link;
      // Unnecessary as "demo3" will be replaced by a table
      // document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = all;
      // Duplicate assignment of kilos, remove this
      // var kilos = document.getElementById('input1').value
      try {
          var table = Number(kilos);
          if (kilos == 0) {
              alert("Please Enter Value");
          } else {

              var output = "<table border='2'><thead><th>Month</th><th>Mince</th></thead><tbody>";
              for (var num = 2; num <= 12; num++) {
                  output += "<tr><td>" + num + "</td><td>" + (kilos * monthly[num]) + "</td></tr>";
              }
              output += "</tbody></table>";
              document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = output;
          }
      } catch (err) {}
    }

    mainPup()
```

```html
<div id="demo3"></div>
```

I have commented out some bits that are not necessary for this - you should add those back in if you need them.  The values for each month are calculated by using the multipliers in an array - `monthly`

Comment: I edited the code and I am now outputting the correct answers but it is now a wide column like this [link] https://imgur.com/a/35KcAse any chance I can make it so it's vertical? Thanks

Comment: Sorry - I updated the code slightly - can you please check again?

Comment: Here is the output [link] https://imgur.com/a/vh4ixME. They are all going into one column, is it possible to have 1 then the answer to 1, 2 then the answer to 2, so on so forth.

Comment: They went into one column because that is how you defined the output - each of the entries in the second column is made up of the `all` value which you have defined as the individual values separated by `<br>` tags.  Do you want the values in separate columns as well?  So each row has 12 columns - a month number and 11 weights?

Comment: Yes I want the values for the months in separate columns, like:                                            1 = 160,                                                                                                                                                                    2 = 40... and so on. Thanks.

Comment: Ok - but you have no value for the first item - you start at `two`.  Is that intentional? ie, are the number supposed to represent the columns in the table, so that column `one` would actually be the month number?

Comment: It might be easier if you explain what columns there need to be - and the headings for those columns and then what row or rows you require and the values that go into each column.  At the moment, you have either 2 columns, as shown in your code, or 12 columns but only two headers.

Comment: Yes sorry i should have said that the months start from two. The first column should be 2 to 12, then the next column after that should be the calculations to them months. so in the first row on the second column should be the variable "two", the second row should be the variable "three" and so on. https://imgur.com/a/PXEuXXK - this is exactly what i want, sorry i am bad at describing things.

Comment: That new snippet worked!! Thank you very much, honestly can't praise you enough. Have a good one friend!

Comment: np - hopefully all my comments in the snippet explained things enough that you can add back in the rest of the code as you need to.